# Filtering over two objects

Tags: angularjs

I have two objects in angular

```
  $scope.data_1 = {"a":5,"b":6,"c":7,'d':1};
  $scope.data_2 = {"a":6,"b":3,"c":2,'d':10};
```

I am clear on how to compare values within an object..

```
.filter('getMax', function(){
return function (data) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, 
                  Object.keys(data).map(function(key){
                    return data[key]
                  }));
};
```

})

But how can I compare the two objects to highlight the greater value for each key?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data_1">
<p>{{item}}</p>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="item in data_2">
<p>{{item}}</p>
</div>
```

result

5,**6**,**7**,1 and **6**,3,2,**10**

Comment: Are you trying to end up with an array that just has the greater value in it? Like data_greater={"a":6,"b":6,......}  ?  Should be easy enough to just create a method to loop over the array and compare and construct and return an array with the greater values.

Comment: Apologies - I've edited it to address your response. I don't want to make a new array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this,or some variation.

```
    <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in data_1">
     <p class="{{computeGreatest(key,value,data_2)}}">{{value}}</p>
    </div>
   <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in data_2">
     <p class="{{computeGreatest(key,value,data_1)}}">{{value}}</p>
    </div>


 $scope.computeGreatest = function (key,value,data2) {
     var ret = "";
     if(value > data2[key]){
        ret = "bold";
     }
     return ret;

   };
```